# How to use use tokens in Sitecore SXA metadata partial design?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa

I use a HTML snippet in the Sitecore SXA metadata partial design to add some links in the head of the resulting HTML:

[image]

This HTML is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents@0.0.1/dist/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents.css" />
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents@0.0.1/dist/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents@0.0.1/dist/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents.js"></script>
```

But I would like to have the base path configurable using for example a token, like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="$WebComponentsBasePath/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents.css" />
<script type="module" src="$WebComponentsBasePath/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="$WebComponentsBasePath/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents.js"></script>
```

where the token is set to: `"https://unpkg.com/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents@0.0.1/dist/sxa-umbrella-webcomponents`.

But token replacement does not work in the HTML snippet.

Any idea on how to make this base path configurable for the metadata partial design so I can have different configuration for my development environment and the production environment, and have the possibility to easily switch the base path on production to roll forward a version or roll back a version of the files used based on a configured base path?